# iOS - web view cookies not set

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am trying to set cookies in my iOS like this:

```
    let url = URL(string: "url")!
    let jar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    let cookieHeaderField = ["Set-Cookie": "key1=value1, key2=value2"]
    let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: cookieHeaderField, for: url)
    jar.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL: url)

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    viewerWebKit.load(request)
```

Then I am printing them like this:

```
    viewerWebKit.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies( { (cookies) in
        cookies.forEach({ (cookie) in
            print(cookie.name)
        })
    })
```

All cookies are printed and they seem to be set normally. But when I use the Web inspector of my safari to see, if they are really set then nothing is there. No cookies are set. What is the problem? Do I need to accept them? Is safari blocking them? How can I set them normally, to be visible in web inspector?

I also tried this approach:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewWrapper: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var loginToken: String?
@IBOutlet weak var viewerWebKit: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
    urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = true

    let newcookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
        .domain: "domain",
        .path: "",
        .name: "key",
        .value: "value",
        .secure: "FALSE",
        .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 31556926)
        ])

    viewerWebKit.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(newcookie!, completionHandler: {
        self.viewerWebKit.load(urlRequest)
    })

    viewerWebKit.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies( { (cookies) in
        cookies.forEach({ (cookie) in
            print(cookie.name)
        })
    })

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func loadView() {
    viewerWebKit = WKWebView()
    viewerWebKit.navigationDelegate = self
    view = viewerWebKit
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    title = webView.title
}

func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore) {
    cookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies) in
        cookies.forEach({ (cookie) in
            print(cookie.name)
        })
    })
}

}
```

but it didn't work too.

This is what I see in safari debug console: 
[image: debug console]

Cookies are not set.

This is what I see in Xcode's console.

[image: xcode console]

So here it seems to be set. But it is not in reality. Printing code prints cookies. But they are not all visible in safari console. How is that possible? Cookies csrftoken and sessionid are set by website, not by my app. And they are visible in both printing and debug console.

Comment: you are doing totally wrong , you are setting cookies in header not httpCookieStore, for which iOS version do you want to set cookies, because for iOS above 11 you can use http cookie store and iOS < 11 you have to inject cookie in header as well as through JS script.

Comment: for Safari you can set cookies through your develop tab inspector and there are storage tab inside where cookie will show.

Comment: Developing for iOS above 11. And that is exactly what I am doing with Safari, but there are no cookies in storage tab.

Comment: no need to set cookie in header then, just set cookie in httpcookie storage.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815182/ios-using-cookies-with-wkwebview/ ? That is my other question :D not working, too.

Comment: oh i already answer under that question :D

Comment: i deeply work on cookie part and its working perfectly in my side.

Comment: urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = true check by setting this.

Comment: cookie not sync immediately. it took sometime. did you cookiedidchange function called ?

Comment: whenever you create cookie , can you see his value exist ?

Comment: As you can see in my code. I am loading request after setting the cookies. They are printed in console, but not set in safari.

Comment: console also showing website cookie not yoru cookie.. it means your cookie are not creating correctly. can you see value of your cookie after creating

Comment: Just tried to print not only cookie.name, but also cookie.domain, value, path and all these things are set normally and are visible in console.

Comment: hmmm but your console showing only two cookie

Comment: Yes exactly. Terminal is printing them all. But in debug console of safari I can see only those two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182341/discussion-between-shauket-sheikh-and-matej-kosut).

Comment: In my case it was domain. It is .example.com for https://www.example.com. the dot was the key

Answer (score 0):

Set cookie through this

```
urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
```

also after request create set

```
self.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie("your_http_cookie", completionHandler: {
    // Do whatever you want. I suggest loading your webview after cookie is set.
})
```

Implement this observers **WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver** in your class.

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.add(self)
func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore) {
    // Must implement otherwise wkwebview cookie not sync properly
    self.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
        cookies.forEach({ (cookie) in
           // print your cookie here
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and just added my entire code and output to my question. You can have a look.

Comment: if in console it showing then it mean it is setting to cookie space of wkwebview.

Comment: csrf cookie you are setting and i can see in image it is there on safari

Comment: Yes that one is set by website and is visible in both safari's console and Xcode's terminal. But those cookies that I am setting in my app, are visible only Xcode's terminal and not in safari's console. So they seem to be somehow blocked or not set properly