# WKWebView does not update document.cookie when setting cookies in WKHTTPCookieStore

Tags: ios, cordova, cookies, wkwebview, wkhttpcookiestore

**Context**:

I have an iOS Cordova application using `WKWebView`. I need to intercept `WKWebView` requests which is not possible using `http|https` scheme (it was possible using `UIWebView` but I have to move to `WKWebView`). Therefore I have set in Cordova's `config.xml`

```
<content src="xyz://host.domain.com/app" />
<allow-navigation href="xyz://*/*" />
```

and I have configured `WKWebView` to handle (intercept) `xyz://` scheme:

```
[configuration setURLSchemeHandler:self forURLScheme:@"xyz"];
```

After attaching the Safari inspector to my iPhone `document.origin` outputs `xyz://host.domain.com`.

Assume a `GET` to `https://host.domain.com/app/foo` responds with the following headers:

```
Set-Cookie: a=1; Domain=host.domain.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: b=2; Domain=host.domain.com; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: c=3; Domain=host.domain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

Using `NSURLSessionDataTask` to make a `GET` to `https://host.domain.com/app/foo` I build the `NSHTTPCookie` objects from the `Set-Cookie` response headers above and store them in the `WKHTTPCookieStore` of my `WKWebView` using

```
[wkWebView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore setCookie:cookie completionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"SET COOKIE\n%@", cookie);
}];
```

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577303). The cookies are correctly set and are retrievable using

```
[wkWebView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray* cookies) {
    //Print cookies
}];
```

---

**Interesting bit:**

After settings the cookies I attach the Safari inspector to my iPhone and:

- Cookie `a=1` shows in the Storage of the Safari inspector
- Cookie `b=2` and `c=3` **do not** show in the Storage of the Safari inspector
- `document.cookie` always returns `""` (JS has no access to the cookies)

**Question #1:** *Why does only cookie `a=1` show up in Storage section of Safari inspector?*

I was expecting to see **all** cookies.  It seems related to the `Secure` flag but might be a bug (or feature) in the Safari inspector because inspecting a random site on Google Chrome shows all cookies regardless of `Secure` flag.

**Question #2:**
*Why does `document.cookie` always return `""`?*

Even when doing `document.cookie="foo=bar; expires=Tue, 14 Oct 2024 20:23:32 GMT; domain=host.domain.com; path=/"` directly in inspector, `document.cookie` still returns `""`, like it is *read-only* for some reason.

Everything worked fine using `UIWebView`, `NSHTTPCookieStorage` and standard `https` scheme. I am at a complete loss in this regard. The only similar questions I could find are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929382/ios-web-view-cookies-not-set) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974353/wkwebview-setting-cookie-not-possible-ios-11) but no luck.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

---

**TL;DR**
iOS Cordova application using `WKWebView` and custom url scheme does not expose cookies set in native code to JavaScript (`document.cookie` is always `""`).

Comment: It's been over a year, did you figure this out?