# iOS WebView - Cookies from WebView seemingly expire too soon

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

we´ve been having problems with our iOS WebView app.

After our user logs in the app (on the web page), a Cookie is created and then WKWebView should automatically save it to device storage. (this is what I surmised so far, I don't normally develop iOS or WebView apps, so I'm sorry if I misunderstood some things).

This works, but if the app isn't regularly checked, the cookie will expire sooner than it's 60 day limit. (can't pinpoint one exact duration, but usually, according to our client, it's around two weeks).

Has anyone met or solved this problem before?

Thank you in advance for any tips/help.

Have a great day!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815182/ios-using-cookies-with-wkwebview
tried this one?

Comment: Any luck with this? We're getting numerous reports from users about this exact issue.