# How to persist Cookies in WKWebview iOS Swift - iOS 13 SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, swiftui, wkwebview

I am looking for solution for `iOS 13` SDK `WKWebview` based app built with `SwiftUI` in order to make cookies saved between different sessions of app usage.

This problem has been numerously discussed acrossed stackoverflow provided with different soltuions for `ObjectiveC` and `Swift` with `Storyboards`.

I am asking the community if there is ready to use code examlpe of how to provide `WKWebView` Cookie Persistency on `iOS 13` `WKWebView` app with `SwiftUI` used

To make it clear: my app accesses remote web server with web site designed to be like mobile app. It's not local web app with need to manipulate cookies locally. Simply to make cookies manipulation in web site from remote server in `Jquery JS` code of the page in order to work and be saved across different sessions of app,

> My current version of code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    WebView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return webView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    let liveView = "https://example.com/projectname/index.html"
    if let url = URL(string: liveView) {
       let request = URLRequest(url: url)
       webView.load(request)
    }
  }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
#endif
```

Comment: is this solved? that is solution? i want to set cookie storage policy enabled for all ios version starting form 10

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora my solution was to fall back to storyboard instead of swiftui and found one of working for me answers on persisent cookies for storyboard. if this is still relevant to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772007/wkwebview-persistent-storage-of-cookies/53512299#53512299 this solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Set the configuration `webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore`

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057088/9333764) for an example